# Cron job failing with firebase in google cloud app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, cron, cron-task

I have used to below firebase blog link to execute a cron job on google cloud app engine for firebase functions but i am getting the below error.

[Firebase Blog link](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html)

Please help..

```
22:47:33.468
 (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:263)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~updateroom-1a8fe/20170705t224250.402458509646721682/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    import pubsub_utils
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~updateroom-1a8fe/20170705t224250.402458509646721682/pubsub_utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "./lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 352
    print('%s:' % h, end=' ', file=self._fp)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

`print('%s:' % h, end=' ', file=self._fp)` is valid [python3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=print_function#print), but not valid [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print).

You can either do a future import to use this syntax in python2:

`from __future__ import print_function`

or use the old `print` syntax.

### UPDATE

Reviewing this, I noticed that the offending line of code is in library code: `./lib/httplib2/__init__.py`

So the problem is that your `httplib2` installation is the python3 version rather than the python2 version.

You can try reinstalling your vendored packages to fix this; the command will be

`pip install -r <name-of-your-vendored-requirements-file> -t lib`

Ensure that you are using the right version of `pip`: `pip --version` should point to a location within a python2 installation.